# React Native: setState doesn't work when calling try-catch function

Tags: react-native, try-catch, asyncstorage

I tried to call APP with this code imported from another file and it worked fine:

```
import FormData from 'FormData';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage';

let formData = new FormData();

formData.append('userId', '1'); // < this is what I want to change
formData.append('key', '***'); //my key

 export function getScoreFromAPI () {
   return fetch('https://www.globalfidelio.com/gfn_arcol/api/transaction.php',{
                 method : 'POST',
                 headers : {
                   'Accept': 'application/json',
                   'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
                 },
                 body : formData
             } )
       .then((response) => {
          return response.json()
       })
    .catch((error) => console.log("l'erreure est:  " + error))
 }
```

but now I want to change my userId from 1 to an constante from Asyncstorage, so I decide to change my code to this:

```
  constructor(props) {
      super(props)
      this.state = { infos: [], userId: '' }
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    this.getScoreFromAPI().then(data => {
      this.setState({ infos: data })
    });
    console.log(this.state.infos);
    AsyncStorage.getItem(USERID_STORED)
    .then((data) => {
        if (data) {
           this.setState({userId:data})
        }
    });
  }
  async getScoreFromAPI() {
      let formData = new FormData();
      formData.append('userId', this.state.userId);
      formData.append('key', '***'); //my key
    try {
      let response = await fetch('https://www.globalfidelio.com/gfn_arcol/api/transaction.php',{
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Accept': 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
        },
        body: formData
      })
      let res = await response.json();

  } catch(error) {
      console.warn("errors are " + error);
  }
};
```

with a try-catch function but when I call `getScoreFromAPI()` in `ComponentWillMount()` I can't setState with received data, I still have an empty array in info:[]

**my questions:**

how can I replace '1' in userId by a value in asyncstorage in the first file ?

if it isn't possible, what I have do to setState info: [] with my data reveived

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's finally done. I tried this and it worked. Thank you to all of you

this is what I have done:

```
...
const USERID_STORED = "userid_stored";
const GSM_STORED = "gsm_stored";
...
class ScoreList extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
      super(props)
      this.state = { infos: [], userId: '', gsmStored: '', }
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    AsyncStorage.getItem(USERID_STORED)
        .then(userId => {
                this.setState({ userId: userId});
                this.getScoreFromAPI(this.state.userId).then(data => {
                  this.setState({ infos: data });
                });
        });
    AsyncStorage.getItem(GSM_STORED)
        .then(gsmStore => {
                this.setState({ gsmStored: gsmStore});
        });
  }

  getScoreFromAPI (userId) {
    let formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('userId', userId);
    formData.append('key', '***');
    return fetch('https://***',{
                   method : 'POST',
                   headers : {
                     'Accept': 'application/json',
                     'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
                   },
                   body : formData
               } )
         .then((response) => {
            return response.json()
         })
      .catch((error) => console.log("l'erreure est:  " + error))
   };
```

Answer (score 1):

1. You're doing your API call before fetching your value from AsyncStorage (I know this is async but it's not very readable if you do it that way).
2. `getScoreFromAPI` doesn't return anything, that's why your `setState` isn't working.
3. You don't need to use `try` and `catch` here, promises have their own error handling mechanism (the .catch() method).
4. I think callbacks are more readable and lead to less bugs than using `.then()` in code.

This is how I would do it:

```
constructor(props)
{
    super(props);
    this.state = { infos: [], userId: '' };
    this.onSuccess = this.onSuccess.bind(this);
    this.onFailure = this.onFailure.bind(this);
}

componentWillMount()
{
    // Get userID from local storage, then call your API 
    AsyncStorage.getItem(YOUR_KEY)
        .then(userID=> {
            if (userID)
            {
                this.setState({ userId : userID }, () => {
                    this.getScoreFromAPI(this.onSuccess, this.onFailure); 
                });
            }
        });
}

onSuccess(data)
{
    this.setState({
        infos : data
    });
}

onFailure(err)
{
    console.warn('Error ' + err);
}

getScoreFromAPI(onSuccess, onFailure)
{
    let formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('userId', this.state.userId);
    formData.append('key', '***'); //your key

    fetch('https://www.globalfidelio.com/gfn_arcol/api/transaction.php', {
        method : 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Accept': 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
        },
        body: formData
    })
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(json => {
        onSuccess(json);
    })
    .catch(err => {
        onFailure(err);
    });
}
```

Comment: it doesn't work, when I console.warn(this.state.userId); here       AsyncStorage.getItem(USERID_STORED)
          .then(userId=> {
              if (userId)
                  this.getScoreFromAPI(userId, this.onSuccess, this.onFailure);
                  console.warn('userid state TEST: ' + this.state.userId);
          }); I have nothing , same thing with this.state.infos I consol.warn it in onSuccess() function

Comment: Did you bind the callbacks in the constructor ?

Comment: yes I did it, you can talk to me in private messages to send you more details ?

Comment: Well, `setState` is async so there's a slight chance your `console.warn()` ia being called before the state has changed, are you logging inside the `setState` callback (see componentWillMount in my answer) or right after ? Can you try logging just `data` (the `onSuccess` parameter) ?

Comment: apart loggint state, I don't have any data displayed on my component. before, when i used userId : '1' I coupld display all my data from infos state

Comment: Dumb question but are you sure your userID is stored in AsyncStorage ? When/where are you storing it ?

Comment: yes of course, I do it when user press login in another screen.   async storeUserId(userId) {
    try {
      await AsyncStorage.setItem(USERID_STORED, userId)
      this.getUserId();

    } catch (error) {
      console.warn('erreur de storage user id ' + error);
    }
  }

  async getUserId() {
    try {
      let userId = await AsyncStorage.getItem(USERID_STORED);
      console.warn('mon user id EST ' + userId); // it display right userId
    } catch (error) {
      console.warn("erreur de storage user id " + error);
    }
  }

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195522/discussion-between-zedart-and-yanick-belanger).

Answer (score 1):

I've simplified your code into a promise chain in which calling `getScoreFromAPI` will execute after getting the `userId` from AsyncStorage, then storing the response into the `infos` state, while returning `null` if there was an error, and logging the error to the console. The data was not previously returned from `getScoreFromAPI`, so the value would always become `null`. I have not tested this code, but this should give you a good base to work from:

```
import FormData from 'FormData';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage';

export default class Test {
    constructor() {
        this.state = {
            infos: null,
            userId: ''
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        AsyncStorage.getItem(this.state.userId)
            .then(userID => {
                this.setState({ userId: userID || '' });
            })
            .then(() => {
                return this.getScoreFromAPI();
            })
            .then(data => {
                this.setState({ infos: data });
            })
            .catch(console.error);
    }

    getScoreFromAPI = () => {
        const formData = new FormData();

        formData.append('userId', this.state.userId);
        formData.append('key', '***'); //my key

        fetch('https://www.globalfidelio.com/gfn_arcol/api/transaction.php', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                Accept: 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
            },
            body: formData
        })
            .then(response => {
                // use response data here
                return response.json();
            })
            .catch(e => {
                console.error(e);
                return null;
            });
    };
}
```